# jQuery If statement - variable from a php post - then do this

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to compare a variable that contains text from a php file. data1 will only either contain "Active" or "Inactive" as returned back by php. I've tried so many variations of things. I even tried getting the value of #activity to see if it equaled "Active".

```
var url = "A_jq.php";
$.post(url, { state2 : str }, function (data1) {            
    $("#activity").html(data1).show();
    console.log(data1);
    if (data1 == "Active") { $("#add").show("slow"); }
});
```

Comment: What is the result of the `console.log(data1)`;

Comment: If your php is doing what you think it is, your code would work. clearly that must not be the case. Debug your php script.

Comment: Could you post the html/PHP that loads your PHP value into the element with id 'activity' please?

Comment: Its not in the php code. I'm using echo statements to responseText back to the browser. The following code is fine and in the above jQuery the #activity is correctly displaying the "Active" or "Inactive" text that is in response from the server. However the if conditional is not showing the #add when "Active" is returned.

                if ($c == 0) {
          $state1 =   "Inactive";
  
  }
  if ($c == 1){
   $state1 =  "Active";
   
  }
  echo $state1;

Comment: -1 I thought the reason you have `console.log(data1);` is to tell if you're getting the correct data from your PHP script? However, you've not provided that output as requested by @tymeJV. Do you still expect us to help you?

Comment: @user3558931 - My response was indicated on my first reply on the 5th and 7th word. :D

Comment: Try trimming `data1` before running logic on it, there's probably a space trailing.

Comment: `if (data1.trim() == "Active") { $("#add").show("slow"); }`

Comment: No trailing spaces =/ if ($c == 1){
   $state1 =  "Active";
   $state1 = preg_replace('/(\s)/', '', $state1);
still same result. no show

Comment: @user3558931 & tymeJV, Trimming worked. How does the space get there even when I correct for that in PHP?

Comment: Use debug tools to view the page returned from your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim `data1` to remove possible trailing and leading spaces.

```
data1.trim()
```